# Footer Widget Styling in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, genesis

I'm having a little trouble trying to style three widget areas in a footer area of a Wordpress Theme.
I have attempted using a simple 'Text Widget' and recently just installed a plugin called 'Call to Action Widget' by 'Charlie Strickler'.

With both options, I am struggling finding the class which needs to be styled or trying to inherit a current style (e.g for the button).

Here is a mock-up I made earlier:
http://postimg.org/image/pp3mateun/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?! We need more information... What is the link for it or provide us a bit of code, what are you trying to do and where, etc etc...

Comment: Its impossible to give advice without a link to your code. You can write css, and write code in a "text widget" by adding a div tag. You can easily create a button like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bevL4a13/

Comment: @Chun, my apologies; so you would recommend to just style the area with in a text widget? The three widgets I wish to style are ID's .section#text-2, .section#text-3 and .section#text-4. I'm finding it hard to explain, so I will have a play around. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Tom25 When you preview the page you can inspect element by right click on the part you want to inspect. See what id/class are effecting the footer (I think you figured that part out). Find the tag in wordpress editor (can ctrl+f and search for the name) and change some of the css. You can create a class for the text (to make it the size and color you want) and I already linked an example for the button. If you publish the page for us to see we can better help you on what to edit.

Comment: @AndrewH Perfect! Yes, this is how I was trying to find the class, as the class(s) did not exist. I needed to add them to the stylesheet like so:

'section#text-3 {
 background-color: #1a1919;
}

section#text-3 .h4.widget-title.widgettitle {
 color: #fff;
}
'

See Screenshot of Widgets in browser: http://postimg.org/image/4y1sne8w7/

I have also applied a heading tag in the title and called the button class within the text widget:

'<input type="submit" value="Download" id="subbutton">'

If you can see from the screenshot and the CSS above, I can't style the widget title correctly...

Comment: @AndrewH Plus, I'm a bit unsure how to add another style for the button...

Comment: @AndrewH Ignore the past two comments, I have styled the widget. How can you target one element to all text widgets? (i.e here's the style for the button within the text widget: 'section#text-3 input#subbutton { width:200px; }'), how can I also apply the same style to 'section#text-4'... If it's a case of copying and pasting the same code over and over, it seems a little unclean to me.

Comment: @AndrewH It's widget.widget_text... Thank you for your help